# Can not find the data correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I execute the cycle and there is a line from the cycle that will match the specified parameters. The message "OK" should appear. Instead, I always get a result "No".

```
request(
    {
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/positions/get',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
    }, 
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('status: ' + response.statusCode)
        if (response.statusCode) {
            body = JSON.parse(body)
            var formData = { Id: 75, Name: 'CEO' }
            for (var i = 0; i < body.rows.length; i++ ) {
                if (body.rows[i] === formData) {
                    console.log('Ок')
                } else {
                    console.log('No')
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer:

```
> console.log(body.rows)

[ { Id: 1, Name: 'Engineer' }, ..., ... 61 more items ]
```

Comment: Can you please add the rest of your code?

Comment: @JackBashford The rest of the code does not affect the request.

Comment: We definitely would like to see the `console.log` of `body.rows`.

Comment: @holydragon Added result to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (body.rows[i] === formData) {
```

This line should be (if you want to check only Id)

```
if (body.rows[i].Id === formData.Id) {
```

or (if you want to check both Id and Name)

```
if (body.rows[i].Id === formData.Id && body.rows[i].Name === formData.Name ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see

```
{ Id: 75, Name: 'CEO' } === { Id: 75, Name: 'CEO' } // return false
```

You should parse it to a string before compare because it's an object

```
JSON.stringify({ Id: 75, Name: 'CEO' }) === JSON.stringify({ Id: 75, Name: 'CEO' }) // true
```

the code should be

```
if (JSON.stringify(body.rows[i]) === JSON.stringify(formData)) {
   console.log('Ок')
} else {
    console.log('No')
}
```

Or you can use `lodash` for fast compare

```
_.isEqual(body.rows[i], formData)
```